# Running Arquillian with TestNG results in NPE

Tags: testng, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to simply translate the Arquillian example [arquillian-persistence-tutorial](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-examples/tree/master/arquillian-persistence-tutorial) into a TestNG test. I've replaced the according dependencies (`junit:junit` => `org.testng:testng`, `org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container` => `org.jboss.arquillian.testng:arquillian-testng-container`) and updated the source code (https://gist.github.com/thomas-mc-work/a296ac40caa402b5120a).

When I run the test then I get two `NullPointerEception`'s: Lines 108 and 98. Both positions mark the first access to the injected `EntityManager`. Also the method `arquillianBeforeTest` isn't being executed as expexted. Also not with the classic TestNG like style via `@BeforeMethod`.

Comment: Are any of the other Arquillian methods running as you would expect? Have you looked at http://jayshaughnessy.blogspot.com/2012/11/arquillian-and-testng.html ? TestNG has always been flaky with Arquillian :(

Comment: Now I tried a very simple example test class and considered that the Arquillian methods are not being invoked. But the test methods are :-/ Yes, I saw that link, and I was a bit worried. I use TestNG as UnitTest framework in all my projects. I don't want to drop this general decision just because arquillian has some (unnecessary) side effects :-(

Comment: Now I've found the solution within the link you've posted. Feel free to post that as an answer with an advice to the method `inContainer()` to detect whether the invocation is inside or outside the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check in your tests using the `inContainer()` method to see if your tests are running in the server/container. There's more information at http://jayshaughnessy.blogspot.com/2012/11/arquillian-and-testng.html

The solution is to use the Annotations from TestNG `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod`. The important difference is that TestNG is being invoked twice per each test by Arquillian: once inside and once outside the container. Outside comes first where the `EntityManager` can not be injected. So you have to ask whether you are inside or outside:

```
@ArquillianResource
protected InitialContext initialContext;

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;

protected boolean inContainer() {
    // If the injection is done we're running in the container.
    return (null != initialContext);
}

@BeforeMethod
protected void beforeMethod() {
    if(inContainer()) {
        // use the EntityManager
    }
}
```